# IGrouping several groups to View

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework, viewmodel, grouping

How would I construct the ViewModels that this query selects?

```
var result =
from company in repository.CompanyRepository.Get()
join account in repository.AccountRepository.Get() on company.Uid equals account.UserId
from notice in company.Notices
join request in
    repository.RequestRepository.Get() on
    notice.SubcategoryId equals request.Subcategoryid
group new {notice, request} by new {company, account}
into g
select new {g.Key, value = g};
```

I am playing around with different types but I can't figure it out.

```
IQueryable<IGrouping<IGrouping<Company, Account>, IGrouping<Notice, Request>>> testGroup;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so you can call `ToList` for execute it and drop `IGgrouping` also you can a bit change `select clause` like

```
select new ViewModelClass{Company=g.Key.Company, Account=g.Key.Account, Notices=g.Select(n=>n.notice), Requests=g.Select(r=>r.request)}
```

where `viewModelClass` something like this

```
class ViewModelClass{
    public Company Company { get; set; };
    public Account Account { get; set; };
    public IEnumerable<Notice> Notices { get; set; };
    public IEnumerable<Request> Requests { get; set; };
}
```

possibly you need use `IQueryable` instead of `IEnumerable`

Comment: Thanks, but there is a difference here. I want to group the requests by notice. With my query I can loop trough companies and for each company loop trough the notices and for each notice group get the requests within that group.

Comment: @Josef but in your code you does not group requests by notice

Comment: Hm strange. this is the loop I use.
            foreach (var res in result)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(res.Key.account.Email);
                foreach (var notice in res.value)
                {
                    
                    Debug.WriteLine(notice.request.RequestId);
                }
            }

Comment: oh! `res.value` is not `notice`! it anonymous class with two field `notice` and `request`, so in your case you also can write `notice.notice`

Comment: Hm sorry but I can't get it to produce the same results. I am not able to get to the point where I can access notice and requests like i did. There is something missing with the key value pair I had before. I will try to laborate a little.